# How do I get the value of a cell in a shared row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a class that specializes DataGridViewCell and handles painting differently. It also needs to override the GetPreferredSize function to request a good size for the content it wants to paint. The [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.paint.aspx) function gets "value" and "formattedValue" as arguments but the [GetPreferredSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.getpreferredsize.aspx) function only gets a rowIndex.

I would like to know the correct way to retrieve the value of the cell (necessary for calculating the optimal size).

If I understand correctly I should avoid doing something like this:

`text = (string)this.DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[this.ColumnIndex].Value;`

to avoid unsharing the row. Possibly relevant: I am using the DataGridView in virtual mode.

Comment: You seem to have meticulously described your issue and I am still having a hard time understanding what it is. Could you please elaborate some more?

Comment: I need a version of the line that I posted that does not lead to unsharing of the row. With some fiddling I could just get the value the same way as in the handling of my CellValueNeeded handler but wanted to make sure that is the appropriate way since I seem to have a tendency to misuse winforms.

Comment: What do you mean by `unsharing of the row`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
text = (string)this.DataGridView.CurrentCell.Value;
```

Comment: CurrentCell won't do it, he has to be able to use the `rowIndex` parameter.